# React Native TextInput how to start overflown text from left?

Tags: react-native, textinput

I need to align this long text and it should start from left. As shown in the following image the end of the text is nicely displayed and start is hidden.
How to start the text from left,

```
alignText: 'left'
```

didnt work.

```
  Geocoder.geocodePosition({
    lat: origin.latitude,
    lng: origin.longitude
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res[0]);
    this._destination.setAddressText(res[0].formattedAddress);
  });
```

Here the formattedAddress is very long, I need to show it from the begining.

By default this is working in iOS.

[image: The overflown text]

Comment: Please update your question with your code.

Comment: @VahidBoreiri added the code

Comment: Did you get a solution for this????

Comment: @Benedict I did it, but not in a proper way, What I did was truncate the whole text from end, keeping only the amount visible

Answer (score 2):

try maxLength. assign value for maxlength according to visible text size. Otherwise use multiline=true if you want to show the full text.

ex:

```
<TextInput maxLength={50} />
```

Read more about it:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#maxlength

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html#multiline

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about flex box system in react native :

```
flexDirection : 'row' -> used to set the text in row direction.

alignSelf : 'flex-start' -> used to set the start from the left.
```

Also please read it from there [React Native Basics flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html)

Comment: <View style={{ flexDireciton :'row', alignSelf : 'flex-start'}}> 
   <View>
        <Text>This is my text</Text>
   </View>
</View>
With the help of View if it is not working then try out 
justifyContent with it.

Comment: Please edit your question that where u put up your css in your code. so that i can setup it accordingly